# Calculating k-th Dirichlet root of invertible arithmetic function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $f$ be an arithmetic function $f^{*k}:=f*...*f$ k times be the k-th Dirichlet convolution. An arithmetic function $g$ is said to be a k-th Dirichlet root of an arithmetic function $f$ if $g^{*k}=f$.
Show that if $f(1)\neq 0$ then has exactly k Dirichlet roots. Moreover, if $f$ is multiplicative then exactly one of the k roots is also multiplicative.

I've thought about defining $g$ inductively but I get a mess of a condition when applying the definition of the Dirichlet convolution. Thanks in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, you just need to use a nicer definition of the Dirichlet convolution:
$$f*g(n)=\sum_{ab=n}f(a)g(b)$$
So
$$f^{*k}(n)=\sum_{a_1\cdots a_k=n}f(a_1)\cdots f(a_k)$$
Then the induction is pretty straightforward: there are $k$ choices for $g(1)$, and the recurrence gives us a linear equation for $g(n)$ in terms of the previously selected values.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind expanding a bit on the recurrence?

Comment: Specificly the multiplicative root. I set $g(1)=1$ but can't show the multiplicative property.

Comment: What I meant by recurrence is if you know the values of $f$ and you've already chosen $g(1),\ldots,g(n-1)$ then by considering $f(n)=g^{*k}(n)$ you get an equation in one unknown, $g(n)$.

Comment: I think we can prove the multiplicativity with a double induction argument. Take $m,n$ coprime and expand both sides of $g^{*k}(m)g^{*k}(n)=g^{*k}(mn)$. On the LHS you can expand the product of two sums, and start combining factors so it looks like the RHS, using the inductive hypothesis $g(p)g(q)=g(pq)$ where $p|m, q|n, p\neq m$ or $q\neq n$. You should get an equation which simplifies down to $g(m)g(n)=g(mn)$.

Comment: Indeed. I ended up using double induction on over the power of to prime, i.e. $p^l$ and $q^m$ for $p,q$ distinct primes and $l,m$ natural numbers. Was a bit of work but indeed straightforward.